# A separator different from comma when applying cursor.fetchall()

Tags: database, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I am using mysql.connector in Python to get queries from a Mysql database. However, the data are separated by comma. Can I change the separetor when using the cursor.fetchall()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that fetchall() returns a list of the rows found, so you can then format the rows however you want to.

For example, `print '\n'.join(cursor.fetchall())` would put a newline between each row.